# ASP.NET MVC and Dropbox

Tags: version-control, dropbox

I'm making website with my friend and we are using dropbox for synchronizing files.

It works well but now we have error.

> MyLogger (Ruslan-PC's conflicted copy 2011-12-20)

Does anyone know what we should do?

Comment: Don't use dropbox for this.  Get a proper source control like SVN.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with ASP.NET MVC?  Or programming at all?  If this is just an issue in the manual use of Dropbox then you might try asking at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox marks a file as conflicted if it finds two conflicting changes it can't merge.

The way you're sharing files is not really the best way to collaboratively work. Your best option would be to use something like Git for source control, or a hosted SVN service such as Beanstalk.

If you want to utilise Dropbox (for some reason) then you can create an SVN repository stored in your Dropbox, then you can check out local working copies on both remote machines. Committing the changes back into the repo will update Dropbox and the other users can then update their local working copy with the new changes.

Comment: Or you can get a repository on a site like http://beanstalkapp.com, http://github.com, etc and eliminate dropbox from the process -- It isn't designed for things like this.

Comment: I agree to a point. I did suggest using a hosted version control system, that would be the best way to go, but what Dropbox can and can't be used for is a wide open book. I use both solutions in different scenarios and keeping the SVN repo in Dropbox works flawlessly.

Comment: Another idea would be to use Dropbox to share the actual `diff` or `patch` files..